# How to handle Multiple events on two Buttons click in same Adaptive Card?

Tags: c#, json, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card which has two separate buttons in it. Button 1 is Submit button with action type - Action.Submit and Button 2 with action type also Action.Submit which is supposed to trigger another Adaptive Card.

The issue is that there are only 3 acceptable Action types according to documentation provided that are Action.Submit , Action.ShowCard and Action.OpenURL.

On Clicking the Button the response which is being returned to my Activity Value is of the input choice set only, i cant access the Action

So therefore i cannot filter the button according to the Title also.

The adaptive card json -

https://gist.github.com/NikhilBansal21/39589cfa3fc33f44b273d551b1650

[IN CASE GIST DOES NOT WORK ON CLICKING . PLEASE COPY AND PASTE THE URL ON BROWSER]

I want my two buttons present in same adaptive cards to trigger different custom flows/cards.

Comment: Your gist link leads to a "Not Found." I wonder if it's private. Why not just paste the *__correctly formatted__* JSON into the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you put in a submit action's data property will be included in the payload sent to the bot alongside any input fields in the card. Therefore you can use the data property to differentiate between submit actions.

```
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "1. Recreation",
        "data": {
            "button": "Recreation"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "2. Contractors",
        "data": {
            "button": "Contractors"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "3. Retail",
        "data": {
            "button": "Retail"
        }
    }
]
```

If you were to use submit actions like these, the activity's `value` property would contain a `button` field that you can check to see which button was clicked. Please see the submit actions section of [my latest blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Kyle the solution you gave worked perfectly fine. I have a question though how can we disable some dates inside the date picker adaptive card for example like i want to disable all weekend dates from the date picker . Is there any work around or method through which i can do that?

Comment: As explained in my blog post, the rendering of input fields is the responsibility of the channel client, not the bot or card author. If you want to be able to customize the date picker then you will need to make your own client application. Unrelated questions should be posted as new questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch submit actions **Unknown intent** and check condition at **turn.entities.button.value = "Recreation" or "Contractors" or  "Retail"**

Here is example my Adaptive Card submit button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdnFa.png)